# Hotloading with webpack-dev-server on an external Docker server when node initiated in Wordpress theme directory

Tags: node.js, wordpress, docker, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to configure webpack.config.json (webpack 5) to allow my external Docker server to watch and refresh the browser on file changes. My node project is initiated in the *theme* directolry, not the base wordpress directory, not the app root, and based on all the examples and documentation I'm reading, managing that has confused me even further.

I've been through so many iterations of the config, and none have worked. I think it's just a basic lack of grasping what each setting does and how to use it (even though I've read the documentation and just about every walkthrough and SE question I can find. I'm honestly not sure if it's a filepath issue, a separate configuration issue, or if it's a Docker configuration issue.

When I run my npm build script, webpack watches and compiles correctly; I just can't get the browser to refresh. I don't get any erros. I also don't get any messages about webpack-dev-server running with the build messages — I'm not sure if I would if it's running or not.

Here's the full basic relevant structure of the relevant files. Relatively standard, I assume?:

```
wordpress 
|-wp-content
  |-- themes
      |-- mytheme
        |-- build
        |-- node_modules
        |-- src
        |-- package.json
        |-- webpack.config.js
```

The contents of the `wordpress` directory are served up on any of these four urls. I use Lando with Docker, if that's relevant — and `lando info` shows `hostnames: [ 'appserver.pcsf.internal' ]`, if that might be relevant as well:

```
https://localhost:55430
http://localhost:55431
http://mysite.lndo.site/
https://mysite.lndo.site/ <--preferred
```

Here's the `webpack.config.json`:

```
 const path = require('path');

 module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: [
    __dirname + '/src/index.js',
    __dirname + '/src/sass/style.scss',
    __dirname + '/src/sass/editor-styles.scss',
    __dirname + '/src/sass/login-styles.scss',
  ],
  watch: true,
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  },
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0', // to accept connections from outside container - e.g.docker
    allowedHosts: 'all', // <--using a catch-all here until I figure this out
    //contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'build;),  //<-- doubt I'm using this correctly
    hot: true,
    client: {
      //webSocketURL: {
      //  port: 55430 <-- doubt I'm using this correctly
      //}
    },
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [],
      },       
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: { 
              outputPath: 'css/', 
              name: '[name].min.css'
            },
          },
          "sass-loader", // Compiles Sass to CSS
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

As an aside, is there a better way to live refresh when using Docker? It seems overkill to run the webpack-dev-server at all when the only thing I think I'm using it for is the hot refresh feature.